# Solving $T(n)=T(n-1)+c\cdot \log n,\quad T(1)=d$

Tags: asymptotics

> Solving $T(n)=T(n-1)+c\cdot 
> \log n,\quad T(1)=d$

**Attempt:**

I tried iteration method:

$$T(n)=\color{blue}{T(n-1)}+c\cdot 
\log n,\quad T(1)=d$$

$$\color{blue}{T(n-1)}=\color{red}{T(n-2)+c\cdot \log (n-1)}$$

$$T(n)=\color{red}{T(n-2)+c\cdot \log (n-1)}+c\cdot 
\log n$$

$$...\implies T(n)=T(n-k)+c\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log (1-k+n)$$

How to solve? pleaaassse!!

Comment: Your recursive formula is slightly wrong, see the answers below (you should not sum over $k$, but over another index and only until $k$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

$$ T(n) = T(n-k) + c\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \log(n-i).$$

This holds for all $n-1 \ge k \ge 1$. In particular, for $k=n-1$,

$$ T(n) = d + c\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \log(n-i) = d + c \cdot \log(n!).$$

Comment: I need a big $O$ solution

Comment: How about $O(\log(n!))?$

Answer (score 3):

You do have to remark that for any induction relation filling the form
$$
T_{n+1}=T_n+f(k) \text{ with }T_1=b
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(T_{n+1}-T_n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(k\right)
$$
The first sum is a telescopic one it only has the last and first one left
$$
T_{n+1}-T_1=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(k\right)
$$
Hence for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$
$$
T_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f\left(k\right)+T_1
$$
Apply it for $T_1=d$ and $f(x)=c\ln\left(x\right)$
Then

> $$
> T_{n}=d+c\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(k\right)=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}k\right)=d+c\ln\left(n!\right)
> $$